# Application crashes when i try to start a method to change the visibility of an object

Tags: java, android, crash, android-progressbar

Here is the code for my android application:

XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="los"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="run"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"/>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     boolean visible = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void run()  {
        ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        visible = !visible;

        if (visible){
          progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (!visible){
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

The app is supposed to hide and show a progressbar when a button is clicked. However the app crashes when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, or the exception that's thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
public void run()
```

`android:onClick` method must take one parameter of `View` type, so change it as:

```
public void run(View view)  {
  ...your code here
}
```